# Php Mail going to recipients spam /Junk Folder

Tags: webserver, sendmail, spam, php

I am working for my college website . I wrote a php script ,that sends email using `php mail function`. But the problem is ,all the emails that I send is going into the recipients spam /Junk Folder.

**In order to resolve it** :

I tried all the steps and answers for the similar issues in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) website Like:
*Proper Header
*Accurate From Name,etc
But yet the problem is unresolved.

This is the php code for sending email:

```
<?php
$from_address="webmaster@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$from_name="webmaster";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
  ."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"
  ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
  ."From: =?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode($from_name) ."?= <$from_address>\r\n"
  ."X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
$subject="Web Mail Testing";
$body="This is test Message";
$to="riteshkumargupta1990@gmail.com";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-fwebmaster@{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}");
echo "The Mail is  SuccessFully Sent to :".$to;
?>
```

I am also attaching the original email (that i received in my gmail account "riteshkumargupta1990@gmail.com")

```
Delivered-To: riteshkumargupta1990@gmail.com
Received: by 10.204.8.210 with SMTP id i18csp146000bki;
        Wed, 21 Nov 2012 20:58:12 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.68.219.164 with SMTP id pp4mr1119127pbc.72.1353560291776;
        Wed, 21 Nov 2012 20:58:11 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <webmaster@nitw.ac.in>
Received: from www.nitw.ac.in (www.nitw.ac.in. [218.248.13.200])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id sh10si3456960pbb.293.2012.11.21.20.58.10
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Wed, 21 Nov 2012 20:58:11 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of webmaster@nitw.ac.in designates 218.248.13.200 as permitted sender) client-ip=218.248.13.200;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of webmaster@nitw.ac.in designates 218.248.13.200 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=webmaster@nitw.ac.in
Received: from www.nitw.ac.in (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by www.nitw.ac.in (8.13.8/8.13.8) with ESMTP id qAM50M0h016190
    for <riteshkumargupta1990@gmail.com>; Thu, 22 Nov 2012 10:30:23 +0530
Received: (from nobody@localhost)
    by www.nitw.ac.in (8.13.8/8.13.8/Submit) id qAM50McG016189;
    Thu, 22 Nov 2012 10:30:22 +0530
Date: Thu, 22 Nov 2012 10:30:22 +0530
Message-Id: <201211220500.qAM50McG016189@www.nitw.ac.in>
X-Authentication-Warning: www.nitw.ac.in: nobody set sender to webmaster@nitw.ac.in using -f
To: riteshkumargupta1990@gmail.com
Subject: Web Mail Testing
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:mailer.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
From: =?UTF-8?B?d2VibWFzdGVy?= <webmaster@nitw.ac.in>
X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.5

This is test Message
```

Also while googling I found the uncommon reason for this sort of problem is **`server Blacklisting`** .

Then I use the following Tool to test it : http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3anitw.ac.in#

I got shocked when the above tool test found my  server in the black-list. How  is this  true?Since the original mail that i attached above says ":**`Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of webmaster@nitw.ac.in designates 218.248.13.200 as permitted sender)`**

Also if my server is blacklisted , then how can i find the reason for blacklist and how to resolve it?

**UPD:** 
From **Shadow** Comment : Can "X-Authentication-Warning: www.nitw.ac.in: nobody set sender to webmaster@nitw.ac.in using -f" msg be the probable reason? If yes , How can I Fix it?

Thank You!

Comment: When I was experimenting with this, the problem was that my server had a dynamic IP address. Does this apply to you? It's common to block these sort of servers as they are likely to be spammers.

Comment: @Shadow :No its a static IP http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/218.248.13.200

Comment: Fair enough. The other thing that could flag it as spam is an incorrect sender header. `X-Authentication-Warning: www.nitw.ac.in: nobody set sender to webmaster@nitw.ac.in using -f` looks quite suss to me. Are you sending the email as `nobody@localhost`?

I would try steppping back from php - and attempting to putty into the smtp server you are using.

Comment: @shadow : So How should i fix this error . I am using squirrel Mail SMTP Server.

Comment: I want to add one more thing : 15 days before ,exactly the same code ,same server and same configurations used to send email to the Receipients Inbox ,but suddenly from 2-3 days back , the mails get deliver to spam /junk folder

Comment: Amazing , I never thought this question will be closed by Stack-overflow community.And one more thing - this question is definitely gonna help the future visitors,as this sort of problem is rarely Faced. Too depressed to get this question closed :( :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up SMTP server is tricky and tedious task unless it is ur job do it day in and day out..,   Check if your server SSL certificate are signed properly with an authorized CA certificate., some times it could be the problem of a self signed certificates .,

Or you can also try out Gmail As your SMTP server which solves many problems .., [Link](http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server)

Comment: Thanks Ajet ,yeah I am trying the same.Thanks once again :)